# Alternative to Peak Design Cuff (Camera Wrist Strap)

Tags: camera-straps

I wanted to buy Cuff from Peak Design, but I've just noticed a lot of comments about anodized aluminum adjuster, which can scratch a body or a mounted lens accidentally.

**Is there anyone here who uses Cuff and can confirm or deny it?**

Maybe, is there any another decent camera wrist strap with good reputation in the market?

My stuff body and lens don't exceed 1 kg / 2.20 lbs.

[image]

Comment: This will be closed soon, as these kinds of questions are not within our guidelines. That said I like the Gordy wrist strap :)

Comment: @cmason Why do such posts need to be closed? I understand it is opinion based, but 
In photography, the gear is quite important. Especially for photogs shooting long hours, ergonomics are especially important, not just for comfort but also for health. Good straps/holsters/mounts can reduce fatigue greatly and reduce RSI.

Comment: There are a myriad sites offering shopping/product comparisons on any topic you can imagine. This is not one of them.

Comment: @ChandradharKoneti its in our rules, but more practically, the answers here tend to be more definitive and long lived. SE strives to identify the 'best answer', and opinions cant be 'best'. These recommendations often lead to defunct products/companies in the future

Comment: I have a Peak Cuff, and there's no damage to my body or lenses. If you slide the adjuster to size, there's enough material between your wrist and the camera to prevent any damage.